# bifurcation code

Tags: plotting, map, coding-style

Hi can you help me in graphing this bifurcation image, i can not make the layout with the red thick line

][image]

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far. The red line is the mean of the roots in each column, so it should be just a small modification of the code that you already have.

Comment: What relationship / equations are you using? Have you been able to obtain the bifurcation diagram?

Comment: Yes, I got it from the first image, but the one from fig. B.   I can not draw nor bifurcation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to combine those two diagrams!

```
Gk = {};
For[i = 1, i < 1300, i++, 
AppendTo[Gk, 
Take[NestList[(2.7 + 0.001*i)*#*(1 - #) & // N, 1/2, 200] // 
N, -50]]]
ListPlot[Flatten[Gk]]
ListPlot[Mean /@ Gk]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, you can help me with fig B, it is about the min function of fig bifurcation A